# location.href make target appear in status bar when hovering over link

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc, location-href

I have the following piece of code which when clicked takes me to the dynamically rendered details page:

```
<tr class="itemList" onclick="location.href='Details/' + @item.ID">
```

My only issue is, is that the target URL which would be website/Details/ID doesn't display in the status bar when you hover over the table row and this also means you can't open the link in a new tab (for instance in firefox this status bar appears in the bottom left corner when you hover over a link).

How can I get this target URL to appear in the status bar across different browsers and also be able to open them in new tabs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit obvious, but still a correct answer in my opinion:

Use an anchor element, like below.

```
<a href="details/your-id">Click me</a>
```

Comment: Yes, I understand this, but I believe this doesn't work with entire table rows? I know I can nest the anchor elements inside each individual <td> but this doesn't do exactly what I want because the <td>s have links themselves. I need the <tr> to be a separate link on its own and using javascript was the only way I could get it to work, but now I have no target URL appearing.

Comment: You can use `window.status='details/your-id'` to show your text in the statusbar. It's not supported by most modern browsers. I feel like what you're trying to do here is impossible. For example, how would you want the browser to behave when you hover a link inside that clickable row? Manipulating the contextmenu of your browser is not possible as far as I know, so there's that. You really need an anchor element when you want such behaviour. You could try inserting absolute positioned anchor elements on the go when someone hovers/clicks...Sounds kinda dirty if you as me...

Comment: If I was to do it uses anchors within each column in a row I would have: <td><href="#">@Html.ActionLink(item.Application.Name, "../Application/Details", new { id = item.Application.ID, goTo = 0 })</a></td> and then repeat this for each <td>. Then you cannot click the action link, that it was I was talking about. Do you know how I could make it so this is still clickable?